# Осознать логику написания программы

Tags: c++, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В заранее извиняюсь за корявое объяснение сути вопроса, но примерно оно выглядит так.

Есть программа на qt c++ с кучей кнопок, при нажатии на которые передаются определенные значения переменных в программу и дальше работает код. Мне надо настроить программу так, чтобы при нажатии на последовательность из двух кнопок, в графическом оформлении последней отображалось название предыдущей.

Т.е., при нажатии на кнопку `"button 1"` и после нажатия на кнопку `"button 2"`, в углу или где то еще кнопки `"button 2"` отображалось название кнопки `"button 1"`.

P.S. В связи с моими очень скромными познаниями с++ и не нахождении в интернете как это сделать. 
Примерно вот так хочу чтобы у меня работало.

Comment: Скромными познаниями прикрываться не надо. Надо взять карандаш и бумагу и нарисовать какую-нибудь схему/логику работы приложения. Нажали первую кнопку - сохранили сей факт куда-то, нажали вторую кнопку - и если был факт нажатия первой кнопки, то отобразить это на морде второй. Не хватает ширины морды кнопки - наследоваться и расширить морду и так далее )

Comment: Так мне надо чтобы в кнопки отображалось значение переменной типа string.

Comment: Что вы там хотите отображать на кнопке к логике программы на имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Программа имеет логику, которая продумана и обкатана. Мне просто нужно выполнить локальную задачу, которая не влияет на логику самой программы.